# Is there a way to optimize this code in order to run faster?

Tags: python, optimization, multiprocessing

Hi there I am working in an application and I am using this piece of code to create new columns in a data frame so I can make some calculations, however it is really slow and I would like to try a new approach.

I have read about Multiprocessing, but I am not sure how and where to use it, so I am asking for your help.

```py
def create_exposed_columns(df):
    df['MONTH_INITIAL_DATE'] = df['INITIAL_DATE'].dt.to_period(
        'M')
    df['MONTH_FINAL_DATE'] = df['FINAL_DATE'].dt.to_period(
        'M')
    df['Diff'] = df['MONTH_FINAL_DATE'] - df['MONTH_INITIAL_DATE']
    list_1 = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        valor = 1
        initial_date = row['INITIAL_DATE']
        diff = row['Diff']
        temporal_list = {}
        list_1.append(temporal_list)
        for i in range(meses_iterables + 1):
            date = initial_date + relativedelta(months=+1 * i)
            if len(str(date.month)) == 1:
                value = {str(date.year) + '-0' + str(date.month): valor}
                temporal_list.update(value)
            else:
                value = {str(date.year) + '-' + str(date.month): valor}
                temporal_list.update(value)

    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(list_1)

    df = df.reset_index()
    df = pd.concat([df, df_2], axis=1)
    return df
```

I have no idea where to start, so any kind of help will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: You need to confirm first which function in the function is actually slowing you down, otherwise you might be spending a lot of time optimizing without effect. *Donald Knuth: premature optimization is the root of all evil...*

Comment: Adding to @Buddy: I'd suggest running your code (ideally with a somewhat smaller input, since it's going to take longer running under a profiler) with [the `cProfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html) to get any idea of which function calls are the most expensive. If your program is threaded, you might want to try the [third-party `yappi` package](https://pypi.org/project/yappi/) instead (`cProfile` doesn't collect stats for calls in threads properly).

Comment: What this function did?